# How to hide few details of GrandTotal in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In my report, I am showing both the shape(tickmark) and text as content.
Now I want **only the tickmark** in the rows,columns and **only the text** in grandtotal.
But the grandtotal automatically applies the tickmark to the final value also.
Can i show only the value in grandtotal?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may append dome dummy data here.

Tableau may not have direct options to change mark types for grand total.  As a workaround it id suggested that a calculated field may be used instead of using totals so that different marks in both fields may be used.

I created a calc field (in Tableau sample superstore data) named Gtotal as

```
{FIXED [sub category] : COUNT([People])}
```

and got this view

[image: Preview]